# Create a table using foreach()

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have following PHP code contain 2 foreachs

```
echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
foreach($resultOld as $key=>$value)
{
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $subjects) {
        $checked = $subjects;
        echo  "<tr><tr class=\"".$subjects."\">$key1
            <input type='checkbox' class=\"".$subjects."\"  value='checked' name=\"".$key1."JAN\" $checked/> </tr>               
           </tr>" ;
    }
}
echo "</table>";
```

`$resultOld` is a `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` output and it contains a **two dimensional array**. `$subjects` will return 661 words from the database which means the `$resultOld` array have 661 elements. And after every 12 cells I want to start a new line (`tr`). That means I need 55 rows in the table. How to achieve this using PHP?

Comment: Why do you have 2 foreach blocks?
use one 
foreach($resultOld['subjects'] as $subject){
     ......
      ......
}

Comment: use once td and once tr...

Comment: @SamBattat  fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) is return TWO-DIMENSIONAL ARRAY

Comment: Use foreach($resultOld['subjects'] as $subject){....}

Comment: also this is wrong html

<tr><tr class=\"".$subjects."\">$key1

should be only one
<tr><td>content</td></tr>

Comment: What is the issue here? Is the output the issue?

Comment: @reilg i want to create the tablr like i told in the question.no errors

Comment: I kindof understand what you want. Posting a sample of the array and expected html output would make it easier for us to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a new row after every 12 records, you need to use a counter and check the count -

```
$counter = 1;
echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
echo "<tr>"; //start the first row
foreach($resultOld as $key=>$value)
{
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $subjects) {

        // if the 13th cell, end last row, and start new row
        if ($counter%12==1){
                      echo "</tr><tr>";}
        $checked = $subjects;
        echo  "<td class=\"".$subjects."\">$key1
            <input type='checkbox' class=\"".$subjects."\"  value='checked' name=\"".$key1."JAN\" $checked/> </td>" ;

        // increase counter
        $counter++;
    }
}
echo "</tr>"; // end last row
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1):

First, note that your HTML structure is wrong.  I recommend thinking about this is a little more steps.  Perhaps layout a single row `<table>` HTML structure for reference between slicing it up into PHP

Here's an example:

```
<table class="...">
<tbody> <!-- I recommend using the tbody tag -->
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

There's three basic things to think about:

1. The Table Body
2. The Row
3. The Columns (ie. Cells)

Step 1 is to print the table body.  You're doing fine here:

```
echo '<table class="table table-bordered">';
echo '<tbody>';
//...
<echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```

Step 2 is to loop through your rows

```
echo '<table class="table table-bordered">';
echo '<tbody>';

// Loop Through Rows
foreach($resultOld as $key=>$value)
{
    echo '<tr>'; // start a new row
    // ...
    echo '</tr>'; // end a row
}

<echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```

Step 3 is to loop through each column or cell of the table:

```
// STEP 1
echo '<table class="table table-bordered">';
echo '<tbody>';

// STEP 2
// Loop Through Rows
foreach($resultOld as $key=>$value)
{
    echo '<tr>'; // start a new row

    // STEP 3
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $subjects) {
        $checked = $subjects;
        // Start a new column/cell
        echo '<td class="' . $subjects . '">';

        // Print cell contents
        echo $key1;
        echo '<input type="checkbox" class="' . $subjects . '" value="checked" name="' . $key1 . 'JAN" '. $checked . '/>';

        // End column/cell
        echo '</td>';
    } // END STEP 3

    echo '</tr>'; // end a row
} // END STEP 2

echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
 // END STEP 1
```

Some notes on your code:

- You're printing 2 Table rows instead of printing a table row and a table column (ie: `<tr><tr>` instead of `<tr><td>`;
- You need to print the row inside the first loop, not the second loop.
- The second, nested, loop prints out your 2nd dimension or columns.

For me, I like to use single quotes (') with printing HTML. I do this because I use double quotes (") for HTML attributes.  This allows me to avoid having to escape the double quote character and getting a hard to read '\""' situation, which can cause simple syntax bugs.

Also when running into problems printing HTML, braking the HTML into multiple echo/print statements can help you structure your code and troubleshoot the problems.  Once it's working you can go back and refactor them into a single echo statement, however the performance difference would probably so minor that it's not worth the time.

I hope that helps!

Comment: it is containing 661 cell in a signal raw but i need 12 columns and 55 raws

Comment: <echo '</tbody>';  remove < in the echo

Comment: Thanks. I missed that part originally and I'm re-reading your question.  I'm a bit confused as you state `$resultOld` has 661 entries but your code shows you really looping over the value of `$resultOld`.  Could you update your question with a single row of `$resultOld`?  Using something like `var_dump()` or `print_r()`? I think I need to see your data structure. There might be a diff. loop structure with only 1 loop.